# Event listener for multiple selection in a JavaFx listview

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX listview in my code and multiple items can be selected. I have already figured out which event listener I need to use when an item is selected but this listener isn't always triggered when i deselect an item.
So my question is, is there an event listener for both selecting and deselecting items?

This is the event listener I'm currently using:

```
lvLijst.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue)
        {
            //code
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to listen to the list of selected items, not the single selected item. When you have multiple selection enabled, the `selectedItemProperty()` will always refer to the last (in time) item selected when multiple items are selected. This property will not always change when the list changes - specifically if you deselect any item other than the last one selected, so your listener will not be notified for every change to the list.

Instead, do

```
lvLijst.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener((Change<? extends String> c) -> {
    // code ...
});
```